# react error: Empty array after setting an const

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, axios

please why do i get an empty array when i do console.log(customers) but i get the right response which is status 200 when i do console.log(response.data);. i dont know if i am doing setCustomers(response.data.customers); in a wrong way. please help me

```
 const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    const storedToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"))
    const fetchCustomers = async () => {
      const config = {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${storedToken}` }
      };
      const response = await axios.get('https://exampleofalink.com/api/v1/customer', config);

      console.log(response.data); // status 200
      setCustomers(response.data.customers);
      console.log(customers); //empty
       };
    fetchCustomers();
  }, []);
```

i also tried

```
setCustomers(prevCustomers => [...prevCustomers, ...response.data.customers]);
```

but i still get an empty array

Comment: Move the console.log() outside the useEffect

Answer (score 1):

don't try to console log when react is still settting the values, you will not see the change, but the values are there!

u can place another different useEffect to see the change like this:

```
useEffect(() => {

  console.log(customers);
  
  }, [customers]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you setting a state, it doesn't immediately change the value, it will changed on re-render, so you will see the previous value which is an empty array and can't see the newest change immediately. There are two option if you want to see the values:

1. Put `console.log` outside the `useEffect`
2. Or, add `console.log` into another `useEffect` that run when `customers` value changed

   ```
   useEffect(() => {console.log(customers)}, [customers])
   ```

See also:

- [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)